# Replace BOOST_FOREACH with "pure" C++11 alternative?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-foreach

Is it possible to replace the `BOOST_FOREACH` in this example with a "pure" C++11 equivalent?

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::map<int, std::string> map = {std::make_pair(1,"one"), std::make_pair(2,"two")};
  int k;
  std::string v;
  BOOST_FOREACH(std::tie(k, v), map) {
    std::cout << "k=" << k << " - " << v << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The key feature being keeping the key/value pair in the references to `k` and `v`.

I tried:

```
for(std::tie(k,v) : map)
{
  std::cout << "k=" << k << " - " << v << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
auto i = std::tie(k,v);
for(i : map)
{
  std::cout << "k=" << k << " - " << v << std::endl;
}
```

But none of the ranged based for loop ideas seemed to work. Presumably the ranged based for loop is required to have a declaration before the `:`, since even:

```
std::vector<int> test;
int i;
for (i : test);
```

Isn't valid.

The closest equivalent I can find is:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it!=map.end() && (std::tie(k,v)=*it,1); ++it)
{
  std::cout << "k=" << k << " - " << v << std::endl;
}
```

which isn't quite as succinct as the `BOOST_FOREACH` version!

Is there a way to express the same thing succinctly without boost in C++11?

Comment: Aren't you copying a string on every iteration in the first example? Do you really want that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
for (auto & i : map)
{
    std::tie(k,v) = i;
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This produces the same output as the Boost macro

```
for( auto const& k : map ) {
  std::cout << "k = " << k.first << " - " << k.second << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 this can now be done using structured bindings, for instance:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const std::map<std::string, std::string> map = {std::make_pair("hello", "world")};
  for (auto& [k,v]: map) {
    std::cout << "k=" << k << ", v=" << v << "\n";
  }
}
```

This is certainly what I'd choose to do in newer projects.