# Replace BGL iterate over vertexes with "pure" C++11 alternative?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, iterator, boost-graph

I want to replace the BGL iteration over vertexes or edges with pure C++11 equivalent. The BGL code (from: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/quick_tour.html) is:

```
typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::out_edge_iterator out_i, out_end;
typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor e;
for (std::tie(out_i, out_end) = out_edges(v, g);
     out_i != out_end; ++out_i)
{
  e = *out_i;
  Vertex src = source(e, g), targ = target(e, g);
  std::cout << "(" << name[get(vertex_id, src)]
            << "," << name[get(vertex_id, targ)] << ") ";
}
```

I tried several suggestions from here: [Replace BOOST_FOREACH with "pure" C++11 alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523648/replace-boost-foreach-with-pure-c11-alternative) but without luck.

I want to be able to write something like:

```
for (auto &e : out_edges(v, g))
{ ... }
```

or something like:

```
for (std::tie(auto out_i, auto out_end) = out_edges(v, g);
     out_i != out_end; ++out_i)
{...}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple wrapper over `out_edges` should suffice:

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> using Invoke = typename T::type
template<class T> using RemoveRef = Invoke<std::remove_reference<T>>;
template<class G> using OutEdgeIterator = typename boost::graph_traits<G>::out_edge_iterator;

template<class V, class G>
auto out_edges_range(V&& v, G&& g)
  -> boost::iterator_range<OutEdgeIterator<RemoveRef<G>>>
{
  auto edge_pair = out_edges(std::forward<V>(v), std::forward<G>(g));
  return boost::make_iterator_range(edge_pair.first, edge_pair.second);
}
```

Or even simpler, a function that turns a `std::pair` into a valid range:

```
template<class It>
boost::iterator_range<It> pair_range(std::pair<It, It> const& p){
  return boost::make_iterator_range(p.first, p.second);
}
```

and then

```
for(auto e : pair_range(out_edges(v, g))){
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code provided by you does not even compile :( Please take a look at the source code (with yours code included): http://pastebin.com/Nx7WeMhU

Comment: here they are: http://pastebin.com/LDLRYwNG (Additional I added ';' to line 20, because there is missing semicolon syntax error without it)

Comment: @danilo2: The robot fixed my answer just now, it was missing a simply `<T>` in the `RemoveReference` using-alias.

Comment: Thank you, now it compiles, but when using it like that: for (auto &e : out_edges_range(v, g)){} I got another error: http://pastebin.com/QS5qJQWM

Comment: @danilo2: I honestly have *no* idea what's causing that error. Maybe you're better off with my second solution, I hope that one atleast works.

Comment: It does not work either :( Here is the error from gcc: http://pastebin.com/VLEZ1MYp and from clang (more informative to me): http://pastebin.com/yKxFDJKL (and the source: http://pastebin.com/TbKQidmk)

Comment: @danilo2: I just noticed your `e` in the question is also a simple value - just do `for(auto e : out_edges_range(v, g))` then. The problem is that `out_edge_iterator`s return by-value when dereferencing them, they're so-called *proxy-iterators*.

Comment: What is very interesting it started to work after I enabled optimalization. With -O0 it gives me some errors. It is true for BGL (see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html). Could somebody explain to me why optimalization influences the compilation in such way?

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Graph also provides convenience macros similar to `BOOST_FOREACH` but designed specifically for Graph iterations.

Iteration over all vertices/edges of a given graph is provided by macros `BGL_FORALL_VERTICES`/ `BGL_FORALL_EDGES` and their template counterparts `BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T`/`BGL_FORALL_EDGES_T`.

Iteration over in- or out- edges of a given vertex is provided by macros `BGL_FORALL_OUTEDGES` or `BGL_FORALL_INEDGES`. (Add _T for their template versions). For adjacency vertices use `BGL_FORALL_ADJ`.

Example:

```
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>

typedef ... Graph;
Graph g;
BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g, Graph)  //v is declared here and 
{                                   //is of type Graph::vertex_descriptor
     BGL_FORALL_OUTEDGES(v, e, g, Graph)  //e is declared as Graph::edge_descriptor
     {

     }
}
```

The macros work both in C++03 and C++11.