# Can't remove an edge after having removed a vertex with Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am starting to delve into [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/), which looks wonderful but which I do find pretty hard to use.

Things are starting to get more clear to me as I play around with [this graph](http://cpp.developpez.com/redaction/data/pages/users/gbdivers/boost-graph/images/boost-graph-1.png) example. But I am now facing a problem: an edge from my graph cannot be removed after a vertex has been removed. And this seems to invalidate my understanding of BGL so far :(

Here is the shortest code I have to make the problem clearly appear.

(I identified vertices with integers [1..5] and edges with letters [a..g])

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace boost;

//==============================================================
// TL;DR : Skip to the end of `main()` where the real problem is
//==============================================================

// lazy iterate over the graph: // {{{
#define VERTEXITERATE(nameV, graph, ...)                                       \
    {                                                                          \
    auto GRAPHITERATOR(vertices(graph));                                       \
    auto& nameV(GRAPHITERATOR.first);                                          \
    for(; GRAPHITERATOR.first != GRAPHITERATOR.second; ++GRAPHITERATOR.first) {\
        __VA_ARGS__                                                            \
    }                                                                          \
    }
#define EDGEITERATE(nameE, graph, ...)                                         \
    {                                                                          \
    auto GRAPHITERATOR(edges(graph));                                          \
    auto& nameE(GRAPHITERATOR.first);                                          \
    for(; GRAPHITERATOR.first != GRAPHITERATOR.second; ++GRAPHITERATOR.first) {\
        __VA_ARGS__                                                            \
    }                                                                          \
    }
    // }}}

// Properties of the graph // {{{
struct VertexProperties {
    VertexProperties() : id(0) {};
    VertexProperties(int id) : id(id) {};
    int id;
};
struct EdgeProperties {
    EdgeProperties() : id(0) {};
    EdgeProperties(char id) : id(id) {};
    char id;
};
struct GraphProperties {
    GraphProperties() : id(0) {};
    GraphProperties(std::string id) : id(id) {};
    std::string id;
};
// }}}

// Type definitions // {{{
typedef adjacency_list<
      hash_setS // vecS would allow parallel edges, which I don't want.
    , vecS
    , bidirectionalS
    , VertexProperties
    , EdgeProperties
    , GraphProperties
    > Graph;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
// }}}

// Glance at the state of the graph
void printGraph(Graph const& g) { // {{{
    // Print graph properties
    std::cout << get_property(g).id << " : |V| = " << num_vertices(g);
    std::cout << ", |E| =  " << num_edges(g) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "vertices: " << std::endl;
    VERTEXITERATE(v, g,
            Vertex vertex(*v);
            std::cout << g[vertex].id << " :";
            std::cout << " in " << in_degree(vertex, g);
            std::cout << ", out " << out_degree(vertex, g);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        );
    std::cout << "edges: " << std::endl;
    EDGEITERATE(e, g,
            Edge edge(*e);
            std::cout << g[edge].id << " :";
            std::cout << g[source(edge, g)].id << " \u2192 ";
            std::cout << g[target(edge, g)].id;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
// }}}

int main() {

    // Build the graph
    Graph g(GraphProperties("Graph"));
    const int nV(5); // number of vertices
    const int nE(7); // number of edges
    std::cout << "Created." << std::endl;
    // should be empty:
    printGraph(g);

    // Vertices
    std::array<Vertex, nV> V;
    int vId(0);
    for (Vertex& v : V)
        v = add_vertex(VertexProperties(++vId), g);

    // Edges
    typedef struct {         // store here everything we need to define an edge:
        Vertex source, target;
        EdgeProperties props;
    } BuildEdge;
    std::array<BuildEdge, nE> builds { {
           {V[0], V[1], 'a'} // define the graph topology in this initializer
        ,  {V[0], V[2], 'b'}
        ,  {V[0], V[3], 'c'}
        ,  {V[2], V[3], 'd'}
        ,  {V[1], V[4], 'e'}
        ,  {V[2], V[4], 'f'}
        ,  {V[3], V[4], 'g'}
    }};
    for(auto p : builds)
        add_edge(p.source, p.target, p.props, g);

    // See what happened:
    std::cout << "Filled up." << std::endl;
    printGraph(g); // ok.

    //==============================================================
    // HERE is the interesting part :
    // remove an edge by its vertices:
    std::array<Vertex, 2> toRemove {{V[0], V[1]}};
    remove_edge(toRemove[0], toRemove[1], g);
    std::cout << "Edge removed." << std::endl;
    printGraph(g); // ok.

    // remove a vertex:
    toRemove[0] = V[3];
    clear_vertex(toRemove[0], g);
    remove_vertex(toRemove[0], g);
    std::cout << "Vertex removed" << std::endl;
    printGraph(g); // success.

    // remove another vertex:
    toRemove = {{ V[2], V[4] }};
    remove_edge(toRemove[0], toRemove[1], g);
    std::cout << "Edge removed." << std::endl;
    printGraph(g); // FAIL!

    // Why does this fail?
    // Is `V` outdated after a call to remove_edge?
    //==============================================================

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Why does the last removal not happen? Of course, deleting the intermediate block (i.e. keeping the fourth vertex) will allow the edge to be correctly removed.

I am aware that removing an edge after one of its bound vertices has been removed does not make much sense, but this is precisely not the case here.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but looking at your `(VERTEX/EDGE)ITERATE` I think you may be interested in the [iteration macros](http://www.boost.org/boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp) provided by the library. Sadly I think they are undocumented but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20037019/2417774) you can find an overview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wop! `just found a [really interesting page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) on this topic. This is the official Boost documentation.

Defining an `adjacency_list` with `VertexList = vecS` causes all vertex descriptors to be invalidated by a call to `remove_vertex`. Choosing another data structure such as `hash_setS` will keep them valid.

Therefore: rewriting the typedef:

```
typedef adjacency_list<
      hash_setS // vecS would allow parallel edges, which I don't want.
    , hash_setS // vecS would make the descriptor invalid on graph change
    , bidirectionalS
    , VertexProperties
    , EdgeProperties
    , GraphProperties
    > Graph;
```

solves the problem.

Not only does it do so, but it also affect other properties of the [`adjacency_list`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) such as the underlying algorithms complexity. This still looks quite intricate to me as I am new to BGL, but see the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html). :)

Comment: This is a true tidbit but it completely skips over many nontrivial interface and performance changes. This signifies a lack of personal experience with the library. People can be assumed toread the docs and Google on their own accord. This site is for expert input IMO

Comment: @sehe Indeed. As I said, I am only starting to use BGL, and as you say, this is nontrivial. I will enforce that point in the answer.

Comment: Oops. In fact i didn't notice at all that you answered your own question :) feel free to disregard my comment in that context.

Comment: [This other page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:choosing-graph-type) from the docs is likely also interesting to future visitors. It talks about the runtime impact of this choice.